# How to have a function outside Vue instance have proper `this` context?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm having a great deal of trouble with my Vue component.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ElForm } from 'element-ui/types/form';

type Validator = (
  this: typeof PasswordReset,
  rule: any,
  value: any,
  callback: (error?: Error) => void
) => void;

const validatePass1: Validator = function(rule, value, callback) {
  if (value && this.form.passwordConfirm) {
    (this.$refs.form as ElForm).validateField('passwordConfirm', valid => {});
  }
};

const PasswordReset = Vue.extend({
  // ...
```

In the `validatePass1` func, `this.form` is underlined as an error, as is `this.$refs`. Respectively:

"Property 'form' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<{ form: { password: string; passwordConfirm: string; }; rules: { password: ({ requ...'."

"Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<{ form: { password: string; passwordConfirm: string; }; rules: { password: ({ requ...'."

How do I get this function to recognize refs/props/data attached to my component?

Answer (score 1):

you can instantiate vue globally,

```
window.vm = new Vue ({...});
```

and referencing it anywhere in your ts file like

```
window.vm.$refs.form
```